# element.getAttribute("value") returning null from input element

Tags: typescript, protractor, ui-automation

I'm testing a UI using protractor

I'm doing the following

```js
const input_field = element(by.name(name_here));
input_field.getAttribute('value').then(val=>{
    console.log(val
});
```

And this always prints null, which is weird because when I do it in the browser's console like this:

```js
document.getElementsByName(name_here)[0].value it prints the correct value.
```

Comment: I tried that, and it returns undefined...

Comment: Here's what I'm doing
const missName = element(by.name(name_here);
console.log(missName.value);

And that is printing(undefined) to the console.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comments. I totally missed the `protractor` part :/

Comment: :'(
It's okay, thanks for trying.

Comment: this question has been asked 5 times this week. It's because of the bug in chromedriver v91

Comment: I am observing the same thing. It appears to be related to Chrome and not protractor. I could reproduce this with laytest Chrome only.

Comment: I'm also only reproducing it with chromebrowser v91. So I'm guessing that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for now and up until this bug gets fixed, you could use

```js
browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].value', inputElement);
```

where inputElement is of type ElementFinder

Answer (score 0):

## Temp solution

I found a workaround that just worked with chrome `91.0.4472.114` on mac

The problem described here is actually a bug in chromedriver https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1205107 so it is not Protractor problem only

While it's being worked on, **you can use chromedriver version 90**. Works like a charm. The latest version available is here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_90.0.4430

You can downgrade chromedriver by running this command

```
webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome 90.0.4430.24
```

Note sometimes you have global, project local and Protractor specific installations of webdriver-manager. The command I gave will install chromedriver globally. In order to install locally you need to find the path to your webdriver-manager and run command like this

```
node ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome 90.0.4430.24
```

And some of you may need to run command in `sudo` mode. Keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# this works, once you have your fields defined:

```
IWebElement inputField= driver.FindElement(By.Id("inputFieldId"));
IWebElement headingLabel= driver.FindElement(By.Id("headingLabelId"));
```

For `<p>` tags etc.:

```
string HeadingValue = headingLabel.Text;
```

And this works for input fields:

```
string FieldValue = inputField.GetAttribute("value");
```

You can combine them to check against each other if necessary like this:

```
Assert.Equal(inputField.GetAttribute("value"), headingLabel.Text);
```

Or NotEqual:

```
Assert.NotEqual(inputField.GetAttribute("value"), headingLabel.Text);
```

ChromeDriver v.96.0.4664.4500

WebDriver v.4.0.1

Might help someone who ends up here from a Google search at some point.